Inconsistencies between Azure OpenAI Chat Playground and .NET API Outputs
I've been working on a project recently, where the goal is to extract the main topic mentioned multiple times in a given text. To achieve this, I've been using a consistent prompt with the same set of parameters in two environments: the Azure OpenAI Chat Playground and directly within a .NET application using the GetChatCompletions() function.
Here's where it gets interesting: with one example text, when using the Chat Playground, the output reliably identifies one main topic as expected. However, running the exact same prompt and parameters through my .NET code results in the identification of two or even three topics within the output. Notably, some of these topics are mentioned only once in the text, diverging from my project's objective.
This discrepancy has left me puzzled. Could there be additional parameters or settings applied by the Chat Playground that aren't visible or accessible to us users? I'm reaching out to see if anyone else has encountered a similar situation or if there's any insight into why this might be happening.
Your expertise and any advice on how to achieve consistent results across both platforms would be greatly appreciated. Could it be a hidden parameter or a difference in how the environments process the prompts?
Looking forward to your thoughts and suggestions!
Parameters that I am using: Temperature: 0.2, MaxTokens: 800, NucleusSamplingFactor: 0.95, FrequencyPenalty: 0, PresencePenalty: 0, ChoiceCount: 1
In Chat playground, Past messages included: 1. My .NET code also only includes one past message from user.
Both of them are using the same model deployment.
Prompt:
You are a product review assistant that detects issues from customers' reviews and you will help product team summarize the prominent issues associated with the prodcuts by following these guidelines:  
    1. Review the provided text in XML format, specifically focusing on the 'review' tag.  
    2. Base your analysis strictly on the provided reviews, without including external information.   
    3. Keep your output concise and focused on the key details related to product problems.  
    4. If multiple prominent issues are found, provide separate summaries for each.  
    5. Consider a problem to be widespread only if it is mentioned in multiple reviews with similar keywords, patterns, and nature of the issue.   
    6. If more than 5 reviews are provided by users, only include issues mentioned in 5 or more reviews in the summary, excluding any isolated problems. If less than 5 reviews are provided, include all systemic issues regardless of their frequency in the summary.  
    7. Combine reviews about the same system component into a single entry to avoid redundancy.  
    8. Begin each issue with a bolded title summarizing the problem, followed by detailed information in this structured format with bolded category names:   
    - Symptom: Describe the issue users are experiencing.  
    - Workaround: Provide any user-found workarounds or solutions.   
    - Frequency Count: Count the number of times this issue is mentioned in the reviews.  
    If any above category is not mentioned in the given reviews, do not include the category name in the summary.  

Code:
string endpoint = "xxxxxx";
string key = "yyyy";
OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(key));

public ChatCompletionsOptions GetSummary(string parameters, string deploymentName, string prompt, string input){

ChatCompletionsOptions chatCompletionsOptions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatCompletionsOptions>(parameters);
chatCompletionsOptions.DeploymentName = deploymentName;
chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatRequestSystemMessage(prompt));
chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatRequestUserMessage(input));

// Call the OpenAI API to summarize the XML text
Response<ChatCompletions> response = _client.GetChatCompletions(chatCompletionsOptions);
}


Would it be possible to share the code, prompt and some input examples?

Hi @MatthijsvanderVeer, thanks for your reply. Please find the prompt and code in the updated post. As the data I used cannot be shared publicly, I'm sorry I cannot provide the input examples. They are all plain English text and reviews for some products.

Without sample input (and I understand you can't share it) I get the same results in the Playground and in code. I tested this with GPT3.5-turbo. I generated fake XML reviews to test this and I can't be sure that's what differs.
Only thing I can guess by the code is that your parameters are not deserialised properly and therefor making strange results?

Thanks @MatthijsvanderVeer for testing it! I am using GPT-4 model 1106-Preview version (GPT-4 Turbo). Would it matter?

I just ran the test again with gpt-4-turbo and the results remain the same (very similar in code and in Studio. This job should be very easy for gpt-3.5-turbo, but that's besides the point. LLMs remain non-deterministic, but you shouldn't be seeing one type of result in code and another completely different type of result in the studio.
Have you double checked that the deserialisation of your JSON parameters works? What if you hard-code the values?

@MatthijsvanderVeer thanks very much for the follow up. I double checked the deserialization of the JSON parameters and it matches. I also tried to hard-code the values and still, the output was different from what I saw in the Chat Playground. Now I have no idea what I can try out then.
